# Updating JTable issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

I have created a `JTable table`

```
String[] ColumnNames = { "Name" , "Father Name", "D.O.B" };
Object[][] data;    
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(pane);
```

So what I want to do is when I populate `Object data` (not initialized yet, but it get populated correctly no issue here), table rows should also be updated with new data and when I search again and If no result is found then table should be empty.

In short I want to update table every time I hit "Search" button. Increase/Decrease in rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `TableModel` and set it to the instance of `JTable` on the view.  The change will automatically update the table.

This will require you to make `table` an instance variable within the class...

[How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) might help

Comment: Why can't I do this with DefaultTableModel ?

Comment: It will depend. Do you want to do a selective update, remove a few rows, add a few rows, or completely update the entire data (remove every thing and start afresh)?

Comment: I have to start fresh every time.

Comment: So the simplest thing is to use a new `TableModel` (like a new `DefaultTableModel`), as removing the rows and adding the rows would trigger at least two updates, where as setting the model would do the same thing in a single update

Comment: I am using model.firetableDataChanged(); but its not updating the table accordingly.

Comment: 1- Make sure that you are only calling `firetableDataChanged` from within the context of the model (not externally) and 2- That the model you are referencing is the same model that the table is using